# How to get value from the select tag to the database

Tags: php

I can post my form into database but I'm getting only 0 as value for the select tag, how can I get value for each select option in my database?

```
<select class="span6" name="test_name">
<?php
include ('include/connect.php');

$query1 = "SELECT test_name FROM mst_test ORDER BY test_name ASC";
$result = mysql_query($query1);

while(list($test_name)=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<option value ='$test_name' selected>$test_name</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: `mysql_query()` is deprecated from latest PHP version.

Comment: every value will be selected this way as per your while loop

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="span6" name="test_name">
  <?php
  include ('include/connect.php');
  $query1 = "SELECT test_name FROM mst_test ORDER BY test_name ASC";
  $result = mysql_query($query1);
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {?>
    <option value ="<?php echo $row['test_name'];?>"><?php echo $row['test_name'];?></option>
  <?php }?>
</select>
```

[**NOTE**: [The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli)

Comment: Pls whats the difference between using the mysql and mysqli syntax, is it just the character changes or there is more to it?

Comment: Pls am still getting only 0 inside my db, dou my db column is int cos i only want the numeral value for each selected. What am i missing pls?

Comment: this is my insert script
if($_POST[submit]=='submit' || strlen($_POST['test_name'])>0 )
$msg=array();
foreach($_REQUEST as $key=>$val){
  $$key=$val;
}
include ('include/connect.php');
$sql="INSERT INTO mst_question (test_id,que_desc,ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4,true_ans) VALUES ('$test_name','$question','$ans_1','$ans_2','$ans_3','$ans_4','$correct_ans')";
  $result= mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
    $res='Question Successfully Created.';

 }

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="span6" name="test_name">
<option value="">Please select</option>
  <?php
  include ('include/connect.php');
  $query1 = "SELECT test_name FROM mst_test ORDER BY test_name ASC";
  $result = mysql_query($query1);
  while ($test_name = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo "<option value='{$test_name['test_name']}'>{$test_name['test_name']}</option>";
  }
  ?>
</select>
```

I strongly suggest that you switch to [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.pdo.php)